# Multiple Get requests in one controller

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, controller, routes

I'm attempting to create my own backend for the first time, but I can't figure out how to have multiple Get requests using the same controller. I get the error "The request matched multiple endpoints." So my question is, how can I specify which method to call within the controller? Is this even possible or do I need to have a new controller for each Get request? The two methods that I would like to access are `GetSummoner` and `GetMatchHistory`. My controller looks like this so far:

```
public class SummonerController : ControllerBase
    {
        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        [HttpGet()]
        public async Task<ActionResult<SummonerModel>> GetSummoner([FromQuery] string summonerName)
        {
            SummonerModel summoner = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(Global.Global.BASE_URL + "/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/" + summonerName + "?api_key=" + Global.Global.API_KEY);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                summoner = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SummonerModel>();
            }
            return summoner;
        }

        [HttpGet()]
        public async Task<ActionResult<MatchModel[]>> GetMatchHistory([FromQuery] string accountID)
        {
            MatchModel[] matches = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(Global.Global.BASE_URL + "/lol/match/v4/matchlists/by-account/" + accountID + "?api_key=" + Global.Global.API_KEY);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                matches = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MatchModel[]>();
            }
            return matches;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I was able to solve this by simply adding the following before the methods

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetSummoner")]
```

And

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetMatchHistory")]
```

Thanks to everyone that helped to answer!

Comment: Try `[HttpGet("{summonerName}")]` and `[HttpGet("{accountID}")]`

Comment: @Youssef13 I tried that, but then I get a 404 not found error: GET https://localhost:5001/api/summoner?summonerName=testName 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#http-verb-templates) - You can find your answer here.

So you have two actions with the same route. The way to solve this is to add a new route attribute or change your `HtppGet()` attribute because it is overriding the path. So the thing that should work is to remove `()` from your `HttpGet` attributes because it is saying that both of these actions are available on URL: .../Summoner/
After removing `()` you should be able to access your actions on paths you want because it will take the name of the action and URL with look like that: `.../Summoner/GetSummoner`

Comment: This worked thank you. I had to remove the () and also add         [Route("GetSummoner")] and [Route("GetMatchHistory")] below each [HttpGet]

Answer (score 1):

You need to define routes for methods like this.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/test")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("get1")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

You can define it in global file also

Answer (score 1):

All u need to do is to set the correct route.

```
[HttpGet("summoner")]

[HttpGet("matchhistory")]
```

Also make sure `[ApiController]` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that's the problem, but it has to be  [HttpGet] (no ())